# copy rows recursively in self-referencing table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hierarchy, self-referencing-table

I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS THING(
          Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
          IdParent int,
          randomtext varchar(255)
        )
```

I would like to copy given list of ids with their children, grandchildren, but when I try it keeps ancient parent Id so the hierarchy is not kept
given something like this :

```
| Id | IdParent | random text |
-------------------------------
| 1  | 0        | "aaaaaaaaa" |
| 2  | 1        | "tt"        |
| 3  | 2        | "third"     |
| 4  | 0        | "fourth"    |
| 5  | 0        | "randOther" |
```

If I give the ids list (1, 4), and another parntid value like "10", it copies rows with id 1 and 4 with the new parent id as 10 but the duplicated children get new inserted parents so it keeps the hierarchy

```
| Id | IdParent | random text       |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 0        | "aaaaaaaaa"       |
| 2  | 1        | "tt"              |
| 3  | 2        | "third"           |
| 4  | 0        | "fourth"          |
| 5  | 0        | "randOther"       |
| 6  | 10       | "aaaaaaaaa -copy" |
| 7  | 6        | "tt- copy"        |
| 8  | 7        | "third- copy"     |
| 9  | 10       | "fourth- copy"    |
```

All i managed to do for now is place all copies into the new parent with this query but I don't want to place all children in the new parent

```
WITH HIERARCHY (Id)
AS (SELECT Id FROM THING
WHERE Id IN (1,4) 
UNION ALL
   SELECT e.Id
   FROM THING e
   INNER JOIN HIERARCHY h ON e.IdParent = h.Id 
)
INSERT INTO THING (IdParent, randomtext)
SELECT 10, randomtext
FROM THING
WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM HIERARCHY)
```

(the query(ies) should work in sql server 2008 and oracle)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: it should work in sql server 2008 and oracle

Comment: some clients are on sql server and some other in oracle. if there is a simple way to "translate" sql server into oracle i can manage it with juste sql server for now (i just need to find the "last insert id" to update parent id)

Comment: Please provide sample output also

Comment: What do you mean by sample outuput ? (sorry i'm french) Do you mean an output of the query I tried ?